# are c# primitive arrays volatile?

Tags: c#

I declare array like that `private double[] array = new double[length]`. Is it safe to update this array items in one thread and read in another thread? Will I have up to date value?

Note i do not enumerate array. I only access its items by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatile does not guarantee freshness of a value. It prevents some optimizations, but does not guarantee thread synchronization.

Double is not guaranted to be [updated atomically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx). So updating/reading arrays of doubles without synchronization will not be thread safe at all wit or without volatile as you may read partially written values.

Comment: `as you may read partially written values` it's interesting. i was thinking that primitive assign is atomic operation... and also there are some more complex atomic operations in this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx

Comment: Normally when you say "update" `operator=` is assumed. If you use proper Interlocked ones it will be atomic.

Comment: Non-atomic updates of `double` is the key to answering this question - I think this should be the accepted answer. Interlocked actually works on array elements (I just tested, didn't think it would work).

Comment: how to perform atomic update of double? Which `Interlocked` method should I use? Will that guarantee freshness? I.e. would `Interlocked` be "harder" method than volatile?

Comment: [Interlocked.Exchange(Double,Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3sh52ebc.aspx) will update double atomically `Interlocked.Exchange(ref arr[3], myValue)`.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not thread safe, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
>   still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
>   exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
>   either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the
>   exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

If you only update single items at a time I think that you will be safe though, but I would not trust it unless I found documentation that proves it.

Comment: i do not modify array. i only modify items in array. i know that array is not thread safe. the question is - are array items volatile?

Comment: See my answer - writes to double are not atomic, so volatile would not help you (and to my knowledge array items are not considered volatile nor can be made one -[volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.100).aspx) ).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not. You should design your locking system with semaphores or other methods to ensure thread safety. You can check [producer/consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).