# Reproduce torn thread reads of decimal in c# with public static

Tags: c#, multithreading

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23263333/963263) regarding reproducing torn thread reads of decimal values in c# shows that this code successfully does reproduce a torn thread.  I am able to successfully reproduce that behavior in my environment as well.  However, if I change `Decimal d;` to `public static Decimal d { get; set; }` the torn thread is not reproduced.  Why is that?

Separately, I am using a series of lock statements to prevent torn threads.  The only way I will feel comfortable that I have permanently prevented torn threads is to be able to generate torn threads on purpose, apply lock statements in the same method I am using in production bound code, and see that the locks successfully do what they are supposed to without significant performance impact. Is there a better way to purposefully generate torn threads?

If changing to `public static` is enough to cause a timing difference in my environment, then I'm fearful that `lock` statements could be causing the same timing differences as well rather than actually locking what I'm intending to be locked.  Is there a way to create a better test rig?

Edit: My environment is - Target Framework netcoreapp2.0, Windows 10 64-bit, Intel Core i7-4712HQ.  Using different Platform targets of Any, x86, or x64 does not impact the test results in my environment.  Neither does building with or without "Optimize code" enabled.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            Task.Run((Action)setter);
            Task.Run((Action)checker);

            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void setter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                d = VALUE1;
                d = VALUE2;
            }
        }

        void checker()
        {
            for (int count = 0; ; ++count)
            {
                var t = d;

                if (t != VALUE1 && t != VALUE2)
                    Console.WriteLine("Value is torn after {0} iterations: {1}", count, t);
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }

        //Torn thread is not reproduced if this line changed to:
        //public static Decimal d { get; set; }
        Decimal d;

        const Decimal VALUE1 = 1m;
        const Decimal VALUE2 = 10000000000m;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I compile the code with optimizations, it tears on my machine whether or not the field is `static`. If I don't compile it with optimizations, it won't tear at all. The exact conditions would vary with your processor and the JIT being used, I'd wager. That it *can* tear doesn't mean there's a guaranteed way to get it to tear. Specifically, if you change it to a static *property*, like you did, the JIT isn't required to optimize this to direct field access, and the method call can throw off the timing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for those details.  Following your comment, I attempted to compile with and without optimizations with no impact to my test results.  I have updated my question with that detail along with other details about my environment.

Comment: You can only observe tearing if the Decimal value crosses a cache line boundary.  The poster of that answer just got lucky, the odds are not actually that great.  I think only 3 out of 16 in x86 code, give or take.  Having no direct control over variable placement is implicit in managed code.  You can play with [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9054170/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion.  If I try the code you linked to in your other answer, it does not tear for me in 64 bit, but if I change to 32 bit it crashes with the message "dotnet has stopped working".