# Lock and Mutex are showing different results

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task, mutex

I was trying out some concepts related to lock and Mutex in C# Threading. However if found that using Mutex gave me correct results while that by using lock were inconsitent.

With `lock` construct:

```
class BankAccount
{
  private int balance;
  public object padlock = new object();
  public int Balance { get => balance; private set => balance = value; }

  public void Deposit(int amount)
  {
    lock ( padlock )
    {
      balance += amount;
    }
  }

  public void Withdraw(int amount)
  {
    lock ( padlock )
    {
      balance -= amount;
    }
  }

  public void Transfer(BankAccount where, int amount)
  {
    lock ( padlock )
    {
      balance = balance - amount;
      where.Balance = where.Balance + amount;
    }
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var ba1 = new BankAccount();
  var ba2 = new BankAccount();

  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
      ba1.Deposit(100);
  });

  var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
      ba2.Deposit(100);
  });

  var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
      ba1.Transfer(ba2, 100);
  });

  Task.WaitAll(task, task1, task2);
  Console.WriteLine($"Final balance is {ba1.Balance}.");
  Console.WriteLine($"Final balance is {ba2.Balance}.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code was giving incorrect balance for `ba2` while `ba1` was set to 0.
This is the case even though each operation is surrounded by `lock` statement. It is not working correctly.

With `Mutex` construct:

```
class BankAccount
{
  private int balance;

  public int Balance { get => balance; private set => balance = value; }

  public void Deposit(int amount)
  {
    balance += amount;
  }

  public void Withdraw(int amount)
  {
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public void Transfer(BankAccount where, int amount)
  {
    balance = balance - amount;
    where.Balance = where.Balance + amount;
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var ba1 = new BankAccount();
  var ba2 = new BankAccount();

  var mutex1 = new Mutex();
  var mutex2 = new Mutex();

  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
    {
      var lockTaken = mutex1.WaitOne();

      try
      {
        ba1.Deposit(100);
      }
      finally
      {
        if ( lockTaken )
        {
          mutex1.ReleaseMutex();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
    {
      var lockTaken = mutex2.WaitOne();

      try
      {
        ba2.Deposit(100);
      }
      finally
      {
        if ( lockTaken )
        {
          mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
    {
      bool haveLock = Mutex.WaitAll(new[] { mutex1, mutex2 });
      try
      {
        ba1.Transfer(ba2, 100);
      }
      finally
      {
        if ( haveLock )
        {
          mutex1.ReleaseMutex();
          mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  Task.WaitAll(task, task1, task2);
  Console.WriteLine($"Final balance is {ba1.Balance}.");
  Console.WriteLine($"Final balance is {ba2.Balance}.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

With this approach I was getting correct balances every time I ran it.

I am not able to figure out why first approach is not working correctly. Am I missing something with respect to lock statements?

Comment: Essentially, and unless I'm misreading something, the first approach is not thread-safe. The first approach locks `ba1` for `Transfer` while the second approach locks both `ba1` and `ba2`, effectively prohibiting changes to `ba2` to occur while `ba1.Transfer` is processed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The first approach locks `ba1` for `Transfer` and also it locks `ba2` for `Transfer`. The operations are running as a separate tasks. Not able to understand why you are saying only `ba1` is locked for `Transfer`

Comment: When you call `ba1.Transfer(ba2, 100);` in the first approach, the lock is taken against `ba1.padlock`, **not** against `ba2.padlock` (and this one is still unlocked)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Your comments are clear to me. Thanks

Comment: I might be misinterpreting something though, so I'd wait until someone with more experience in locks answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with this line:

```
public int Balance { get => balance; private set => balance = value; }
```

You are allowing external code to meddle with the `balance` field, without the protection of the `padlock`. You also allow out-of-order reads of the `balance` field, because of the lack of a [memory barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493931/why-do-i-need-a-memory-barrier), or even worse [torn reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262513/reproduce-torn-reads-of-decimal-in-c-sharp) in case you later replace the `int` type with the more appropriate `decimal`.

The second problem can be solved by protecting the read with the `padlock`.

```
public int Balance { get => { lock (padlock) return balance; } }
```

As for the `Transfer` method, it can now be implemented without access to the other `BankAccount`s `balance`, like this:

```
public void Transfer(BankAccount where, int amount)
{
    Withdraw(amount);
    where.Deposit(amount);
}
```

This `Transfer` implementation is not atomic though, since an exception in the `where.Deposit` method could lead to the `amount` vanishing into thin air. Also other threads are not prevented from reading inconsistent values for the two `BankAccount`s `Balance`s. This is why people generally use databases equipped with the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

The two codes give the same results on my machine *VS2017 .NET Framework 4.7.2* and work fine. So perhaps a difference with your system.

```html
Final balance is 0.
Final balance is 200000.
```

[Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex) are historically and originally for inter-process synchronization.

So in the process where the mutex is created, it is never locked against itself unless it was released like in the code provided in the question.

Using an operating system mutex object to synchronize threads is a bad practice and an anti-pattern.

Use [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore) or [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) within a process if having problems with `lock` and `volatile`.

*Mutex : "A synchronization primitive that can also be used for interprocess synchronization."*

*Semaphore : "Limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently."*

*Monitor : "Provides a mechanism that synchronizes access to objects."*

*lock : "The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock. While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released."*

*volatile : "The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. The compiler, the runtime system, and even hardware may rearrange reads and writes to memory locations for performance reasons. Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to these optimizations. Adding the volatile modifier ensures that all threads will observe volatile writes performed by any other thread in the order in which they were performed. There is no guarantee of a single total ordering of volatile writes as seen from all threads of execution."*

Hence you may try to add `volatile`:

```
private volatile int balance;
```

You can also set the locker object as static to be shared between instances if needed:

```
static private object padlock = new object();
```

Comment: This answer goes against the documentation linked in this answer. If this was the case, and it's not, the second approach would give completely invalid answers. Notice that the first sentence is "A synchronization primitive that **can also** be used for interprocess synchronization." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes. Making the `padlock` static gives consistent output even in first approach. Thanks

Comment: @SwapnilGhodke Yeah, by having a single `padlock` instance you ensure the `lock` also locks the other threads